# uriBuilder returns http:/ instead of http://

Tags: java, url, jersey, uri

I use this code:

```
UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder
        .fromPath(Constants.LIVEMAP_BASE_URL_US)
        .scheme("http");
return builder.build().toString();
```

how can it be that it has generated `"http:/"` instead of `"http://"` ?

returned value = `http:/livemap-tiles1.waze.com/tiles/internal?lineGeom=...`

Comment: where does that class `UriBuilder` come from ?

Comment: Please edit your question so that it includes the definition/content of LIVEMAP_BASE_URL_US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misusing [`fromPath`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.19/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/UriBuilder.html#fromPath%28java.lang.String%29). That method expects a uri path, but you are providing a host and path.

If you have a full URI, use `UriBuilder#fromUri`, otherwise build it part by part

```
UriBuilder builder = UriBuilder.fromPath("tiles")
                               .host("livemap-tiles1.waze.com")
                               .scheme("http")
                               .path("internal"); // etc.
```